# Is there a way to prevent users from unhiding a workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I am familiar with hiding worksheets and preventing users from unhiding them; however, is there a way to use VBA to make a **workbook/window** very hidden or at least require a password to unhide?

For my situation, I must have the workbook open but hidden from the user. The reason I am asking this question is I noticed that, although I've hidden and protected my workbook with a password, I could still unhide it from any other open workbooks.

```
Sub hideWorkbook()

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application

Set xlApp = New Excel.Application

xlApp.Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.FullName  'Assign current workbook to new instance of Excel.

xlApp.Visible = True                        'Set instance to visible.
Set xlApp = Nothing                         'Set object to nothing.

Application.Visible = False                 'As recommended, made application invisible.

Application.DisplayAlerts = False           'Turn off alerts.
ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False     'Hide the workbook opened.
Application.DisplayAlerts = True            'Turn on alerts.

End Sub
```

Comment: You could open it in another instance of `Excel` with the `Visible` property set to `False`. But without further information, it's hard to tell if that's a good idea. Add more info and/or some code where we can see what you're planning to do.

Comment: I meant you show us the code where you actually do something with it. You're not opening it so it could just lay around. Also, `Workbook_Open` is kind of reserved for workbook events where it surely cannot be used.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Thank you for your response! I updated my code to display what I tried. Although I was able to open it in another instance of ```Excel``` and made the ```Visible``` property set to ```False``` it hid the other Excel workbooks. So close!

Comment: @VBasic2008 Okay, I believe I got it. I will post the answer to show what I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to VBasic2008's comment and expanding on his suggestion, the following was what worked for me. Rather than using `Application.Visible = False`, I selected the specific workbook window using `Application.Windows()` and made it invisible.

```
Sub hideWorkbook()                         

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application

Set xlApp = New Excel.Application

xlApp.Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.FullName           'Open workbook in new Excel instance.

xlApp.Visible = True                                 'Set instance to visible.
Set xlApp = Nothing                                  'Set object to nothing.

Application.Windows("MyWorkbook").Visible = False    'Make the specific window invisible.

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
Sub test()
    ActiveSheet.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
End Sub
```